# Command handler with function folder doesn't recognize "func" as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Due to recent failures, I've decided to try and learn node.js/discord.js by correcting my old code. I don't know if it's a good way to, but that's what I'm trying to do. Recently though, I've hit a bit of a roadblock setting up a command handler. For my command handler I have this:

```js
// Calling Packages
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = new Discord.Client();
const weather = require('weather-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const func = require("./functions.js")

// Listener Event One
bot.on('message', message => {
  // Variables
  let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
  let sender = message.author;
  let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
  let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (sender.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  //Command Handler
  try {
    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
    commandFile.run(bot, message, args, func);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  } finally {
    console.log(`${message.author.username} ran the command: ${cmd}`);
  }
}
```

function.js

```
module.exports = {
  ping: function(channel) {
    channel.send("Pong!");
  }
}
```

And for the ping command I have

```
exports.run = (bot, message, args, func) => {
  func(message.channel);
}
```

The line `func = require(./functions.js` is reading the function.js to grab them, and

```
  let commandFile = require(`./commands/${cmd}.js`);
  commandFile.run(bot, message, args, func);
```

allows them to be exported, or so I think. But whenever I run the command "cb!ping" and look at console, it says I've read the command, then `func is not a function`.

It's pretty confusing, I don't quite understand why since I have `func = require(./functions.js)` and its being exported.

I know my terminology is definitely off, but I hope that you can understand, sorry. As always, thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: `const func = require("./functions.js")` will import the entire object you export in the file, so it's not a single function - it's an object with a single method there.

Comment: Should I do something about that?

Comment: Either explictly use the method - `func.ping` or just import that one `const {ping: func} = require("./functions.js")` or `const functions = require("./functions.js"); const func = functions.ping;` or equivalent.

Comment: where exactly should I put ```const {ping: func} = require("./functions.js")```?

Comment: Instead of `const func = require("./functions.js")`

Comment: I now get ```Cannot find module './functions.js'```

Comment: Okay nvm I had the const in ping.js for some reason. Thanks a lot. Would I do the same for others? Like ```{help: func} = require("./functions.js")```